# Generic Interface gets not imported with MEF RegistrationBuilder

Tags: c#, mef

I try to export the following interface:

```
public interface ITree<T> where T : IComparable
```

A class which implements the interface:

```
public class Tree<T> : ITree<T> where T : IComparable
```

In a Unit Test Class I do the following:

```
[TestClass]
public class TreeTest 
{
    [TestInitialize()]
    public void InitialTest()
    {
        RegistrationBuilder registrationITreeBuilder = new RegistrationBuilder();
        //export all classes which implement ITree
        registrationITreeBuilder.ForTypesMatching(t => t.GetInterface(typeof(ITree<>).Name) != null).Export<ITree<int>>();
        registrationITreeBuilder.ForType<TreeTest>().ImportProperty(p => p.TreeInstances,ib=>ib.AsMany(true)); //TreeTest - the unit test class

        var catalog = new AggregateCatalog(
            new AssemblyCatalog(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly(), registrationTreeTestBuilder), //unit test project
            new AssemblyCatalog(typeof(ITree<>).Assembly, registrationITreeBuilder)
            );

        //Create the current composition container to create the parts
        var container = new CompositionContainer(catalog);
        container.ComposeParts(this);
    }
    public IEnumerable<ITree<int>> TreeInstances { get; set; }
}
```

After the InitialTest() method is executed the property TreeInstances is **null**. When adding the container to the watch, I see under container.Catalog.Parts

> {Get.the.Solution.DataStructure.Tree({0})}

with the `ExportDefinition (ContractName="Get.the.Solution.DataStructure.ITree(System.Int32)")}` which should be correct. But there is no ImportDefinition although I set a ImportProperty definition.

Anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

The `ComposeParts(...)` call is actually meant to be used by the attributed programming model of MEF. What you are using in your unit test is using the convention based programming model.

Personally I would not mix those two, but if you want a quick fix here, you just add the `[ImportMany]`Attribute to your `TreeInstances` property and your test project will work.

I would suggest using a separate type here to host the tree instances, exporting it in your builder and getting it from your container in the test with an `GetExportedValue` call. This would mean your test class would look something like this:

```
[TestClass]
public class TreeTest
{
    private CompositionContainer _Container;

    private class Trees
    {
        public IEnumerable<ITree<int>> TreeInstances { get; set; }
    }

    [TestInitialize()]
    public void InitialTest()
    {
        ...
        //add the Export<Trees>() in your code
        registrationITreeBuilder.ForType<Trees>().ImportProperty(tt => tt.TreeInstances, ib => ib.AsMany()).Export<Trees>();
        ...
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod1()
    {
        var trees = _Container.GetExportedValue<Trees>();
    }
}
```

This way you could also add a cleanup method for your test to get rid of the `CompositionContainer` in case you allocated resources you need to dispose.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm using the solution with using the ImportMany attribute. Also I had to fix the export type because it was not matching with the import. Please add the correct line             registrationITreeBuilder.ForTypesDerivedFrom<ITree<IComparable>>().Export();" for a correct solution.

Comment: I'm sorry it seems that registrationITreeBuilder.ForTypesDerivedFrom<ITree<IComparable>>().Export(); is also not working.